# CSS how to make '>' chars go to the same direction

Tags: html, css, textarea, right-to-left

I'm having trouble with a mixed `textarea`, with Hebrew (RTL) and English,
This text contains <, > characters.

The `textarea` is for Hebrew mainly, but sometimes English is used too.
It's RTL.

Sometimes, when I type '<' tag it goes like '>' and sometimes its stays '<'. I need it to be always the same.

Is there any way to make them always go to the same side, using css only?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H34.html http://www.htmlescape.net/20/character_right_to_left_override_202e.html

Comment: Please show sample code (HTML and CSS) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you enter in a textarea, or any text, a “<” character, it will remain that character, but it may be rendered using a glyph identical with the left-to-right glyph of “>”. The reason is that the character is expected to appear so that the angle part is on the side of the smaller quantity. In left-to-right languages, “a

So the *character* “<” stays the same. It just gets *rendered* with a *glyph* that points to the right. Similarly for “>”.

You could override this with a directionality override, but that would mean that Hebrew words, too, would appear left-to-right, i.e. wrong.

I suppose the input might be something like `<p>שָׁלוֹם</p>`, i.e. Hebrew text between constructs that will later be interpreted as HTML tags. This is a real challenge. Inside a left-to-right element, it will appear in an order that looks OK to a person accustomed to left-to-right text: from the left, we see the start tag, the content, and the end tag. The content appears right-to-left, as it should in any case. So far so good. But if you set the directionality to right-to-left, the tag `<p>` will appear rightmost, rather naturally, then the Hebrew word, and then the end tag as `<p/>`, which might look confusing, or natural, I really don’t know.

Anyway, if the input is essentially *marked-up* text, like HTML or XML, then you should probably have left-to-right directionality, unless you expect your users to be familiar with the rendering described.

In any case, there is no CSS way to tell that “<” should always appear as left-pointing irrespectively of directionality. Its glyph is *supposed to* look different depending on the directionality of characters around it.

The directionality of the element does not affect this, since this takes place due to the inherent directionality of characters. But directionality may matter in a longer string of characters which has mixed left-to-right and right-to-left characters.